# No plugin found for prefix 'jasmine' in the current project

Tags: maven, gruntjs, jasmine, pom.xml, jasmine-maven-plugin

I get **No plugin found for prefix 'jasmine' in the current project and in the plugin groups** [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/patthia/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/), sonatype-releases (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases), clojars.org (http://clojars.org/repo), error when I run

```
mvn jasmine:bdd
```

in my project. I am in correct folder while running this command. I have verified my plugin dependency and configuration. Here is my plugin configuration in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```